# UITableView freezes till loop complete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using this code to search text in `Database` tables:

```
func runSearch(_ pattern: String) {
    for book in selectedBooks {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "library", ofType: "sqlite")!
        let sqlState = "select * from \(book.name)"
        
        guard
            let db = FMDatabase(path: path), db.open(),
            let result = db.executeQuery(sqlState, withArgumentsIn: [])
        else { return }
        
        while result.next() {
            RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: .distantPast)
            
            let pageID = result.long(forColumn: "Id")
            let pageText = result.string(forColumn: "page_text") ?? ""
            
            if isMatches(regex: pattern, in: pageText) {
                dataSource.append(dbItem(id: pageID, text: pageText))
                resultsLabel.text = "Results count: " + dataSource.count.description

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: dataSource.count - 1, section: 0)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }
    
}


func isMatches(regex: String, in str: String) -> Bool {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: str, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))
        return matches.count != 0
        
    } catch {
        print("Something went wrong! Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return false
}
```

I have over 40 books to search through. And the search is done fine, but the "UITableView" freezes until the search is complete. I want to allow the user to scroll through this table and choose what result he wants to display while searching.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: What is the `RunLoop` line for?

Comment: To change resultsLabel text

Comment: ??? In an iOS app the runloop runs permanently. And you really have an extra sql table for each book?

Comment: Is there any way to delay inserting rows to table? without using sleep()

Comment: I don't understand why you want to delay the insertion, actually that's the issue of your question but you can do it with `asyncAfter` of `DispatchQueue`. And if you want to do it to make an asynchronous function synchronous it's wrong anyway.

Comment: As I said I want to allow the user to scroll through this table and choose what result he wants to display while searching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233390/discussion-between-w-m-and-vadian).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an asynchronous function where you do all the work and after the function ends call tableView.reloadData. Also, you can not insert rows after every loop but when the whole loop ends and you have the right data in your data source then reload data to your table view to refresh it with the new data.